# How to change the dragged text without changing the original text being grabbed, in pure Javascript?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I can't seem to figure out how to change the dragged text, without also changing the original text from the element. I want to change the dragged text shown next to the cursor when moving the text, not while dropping it in a dropzone or when dragging it over a DOM, but while dragging it anywhere.

```js
function drag(dragevent) {
  dragevent.target.innerHTML = 'bar';
  dragevent.dataTransfer.setData("text", dragevent.target.id);
  dragevent.target.style.color = "green";

}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <span id="drag" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">drag me</span>
</div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

Comment: That is not trivial

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean I tried and failed. I have not yet found a way to swap the text of the dragged item without it also swapping the text of the source span

Comment: yeah, it is far more difficult to achieve than I had anticipated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function drag(dragevent) {
  // cleate a clone of the note outside the screen
  let e = dragevent.target.cloneNode(true)
  e.style = 'position: fixed; top: 0; right: 0'
  dragevent.target.after(e)

  // set it as drag image
  dragevent.dataTransfer.setDragImage(e , 10, 10)

  // do whatever you want with the original node
  dragevent.target.innerHTML = 'bar';
  dragevent.dataTransfer.setData("text", dragevent.target.id);
  dragevent.target.style.color = "green";

  // cleanup the clone on dragend or whenever
  setTimeout(() => e.remove(), 100)
  // requestAnimationFrame(() => e.remove(), 100)
  // requestAnimationFrame does work but sometimes fails to start drag
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <span id="drag" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">drag me</span>
</div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

Comment: That does not work as requested. What did you change and what was the aim of the change? Try adding dragover and drop to see it better. Also `e` is a poor name for an element in something that is event driven when `e` is often used for `event`

Answer (score 2):

Got it to work by altering Dimava's answer a little:

```js
function drag(dragevent) {
  // cleate a clone of the note outside the screen
  let e = dragevent.target.cloneNode(true)
  e.style = 'position: fixed; top: 0; right: 10'
  e.innerText ="bar";
  dragevent.target.after(e)
  dragevent.dataTransfer.setDragImage(e , 0, 0)
  dragevent.dataTransfer.setData("text", dragevent.target.id);
  dragevent.target.style.color = "green";
  setTimeout(() => e.remove(), 1)
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <span id="drag" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">drag me</span>
</div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```